# C# what is the `is {} out` pattern?

Tags: c#

Really hard question to explain! Please let me know what this pattern is called and I'll update the title

`if (context.RequestServices.GetService<Iservice>() is { } service)` and service is the instance.

I have copied this from an example but do not understand the `is { } service` part. It looks like an out parameter, does anyone know what this technique is called so I can find the documentation please? :)

Comment: Well if context.RequestServices.GetService<Iservice>() is not null then it will assign to "service".

Comment: https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpGYZQAs6AsgBQCU+hxTUcADOgM4COANugLzoARABcAphxFCA3IyZEAlgDNq3Pgo74Avp15xac+QSTzTmOAE5Ve2rJNmdxQ1uRagA=
Here is the link to look how lower level conversion look like.